# Kotlin with(String) strange behavior

Tags: android, kotlin, stringbuilder

I have simple block of code wich should parse String like "5555;John Snow"

```
//Example of code without string population

val str = StringBuilder() 

with(str.toString().trim()) {
    card.id = substring(0, indexOf(";"))
    card.name = substring(indexOf(";" + 1, length))
}
```

But when it try to take name, throws an error

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=SOME_LENGHT; index=-1

Debuged and checked, String is correct. It's even work some times in debugger

Comment: `indexOf(";" + 1, length)` should be `indexOf(";" + 1), length`?

Comment: @HonzaZidek it is Kotlin, and it was complilable)

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by `indexOf(";" + 1, length)`, which was visibly not what you wanted and I did not realize that there is also an overloaded method with signiture `indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`. By the way, your error is a punishment for ugly programming style :) Calculating `indexOf(";")` twice instead of assigning it to a variable is the bad style, and the bad style often produces errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with indexes:

```
with(str.toString().trim()) {
    card.id = substringBefore(";")
    card.name = substringAfter(";")
}
```

Comment: "do Y" is not an answer to "why does X not work"

Comment: @TimCastelijns but it is good suggestion to simplify code. I did not know about this method

Comment: *is not an answer* yes but it is the simplest solution

Comment: @AntonA. that is not relevant in the context of this question. I might also suggest you to delete your question, which is a good suggestion

Answer (score 1):

My bad.

Incorrect

```
card.name = substring(indexOf(";" + 1, length))
```

Correct

```
card.name = substring(indexOf(";") + 1, length)
```

Comment: By the way, your error is a punishment for ugly programming style :) Calculating `indexOf(";")` twice instead of assigning it to a variable is the bad style, and the bad style often produces errors.

Comment: @HonzaZidek it is time vs memory)

Comment: Nice try, but *no* - by calculating the same `int` value twice you consume much more memory, which is most probably not garbage collected before your method finishes. And `indexOf(...)` is expensive.